# problem retrieving values entered on a form

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a problem with my contact form and I wanted to test if I retrieve my values from the form but it returns

```
name: undefined
```

/ and I do not see why it does not work!

here is the form code

```js
<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="contact">
  <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />
  <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" />
  <textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
  <input type="submit"  action="contact"/>
```

and the request:

```
app.post("/contact", (req, res) => {

const name = req.body.name
console.log('name:', name)
```

})

thank you in advance

Comment: have you used the developer tools from the browser to look at what data is sent? I think you need to set 'id' for each of the fields.

Comment: yes i test from the form, but how do i do that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools might answer your question.

Comment: sorry but i dont see how that could fix my problem: /

Comment: you can find what data is being sent and you can match your expectation.

Comment: I test my route on postman by putting json with the key and the value and it returns the name to me, but it's when I do it through the form it doesn't work

Comment: its the integration that you are having an issue with, you need to look at whether the data being sent from UI to your route is right. if that is right then there can issue with the way that your app is accepting the request but you say JSON works from the postman.  set 'id' on each field in your form and check if that form action is sending the data

Comment: Thanks for helping me, in fact my problem was that I did not have to call multer XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) middleware.

> Multer is a node.js middleware for handling `multipart/form-data`, which is primarily used for uploading files.

E.g.

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('./index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
app.post('/contact', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  console.log('name:', name);
  console.log('body:', req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started at http://localhost:3000'));
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="contact">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />
    <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" />
    <textarea name="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" action="contact" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Server logs:

```
Server started at http://localhost:3000
name: teresa
body: [Object: null prototype] { name: 'teresa', email: 'teresa@teng.com', text: 'Best singer' }
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you, and that's the problem I had, thank you very much :)